# node-webkit force file download with javascript

Tags: node-webkit

In a static webpage you can do something like this :

```
var csv="1,2,3 \n 4,5,6";
window.open('data:text/csv,'+encodeURI(csv));
```

to save a file, but in a node-webkit app, it will just open a empty page, without downloading anything. Does anyone know if this can be done with node-webkit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this in node-webkit (maybe more that I haven't thought of):

You can just use the node.js `fs` module to write a file, like so:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFileSync('foo.csv', csv);
```

On the other hand, if you want to bring up a standard system file chooser dialog, you can use an input tag and trigger a click event on it.  Details can be found here - https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs